# materializecss + meteor (materialize-meteor library): how to render icons? (or other framework which works)

Tags: cordova, meteor, materialize

As reported as in issue on Github: https://github.com/d0minikk/materialize-meteor/issues/20 (but I don't see activity there which could mean the project is not supposed anymore)

Alternatively to fix this issue, **what is one CSS/whatever framework for Material Design which works nicely with Meteor (1.1+) + Cordova (5.0+)**?

I tried both **menu** (which on official Material Design web site, to Materializecss refer to, is present) and **toc**

```
 <i class="material-icons">menu</i>
 <i class="material-icons">toc</i>
as explained at: http://materializecss.com/icons.html
```

I understand that it may be need to add

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

but where? (since I'm not using Materializecss directory but as a Meteor module. Also I'm using iron:router which doesn't let me put tag anywhere)

**This renders instead**

from the example at: http://materializecss.com/side-nav.html

However this is documented nowhere (as far as I know).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just create a new HTML file somewhere in your project with this code:

```
<head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

Comment: the issue is that I can't add <head> tag manually since I'm using iron:router

Answer (score 0):

Even though I can't add a head tag manually while using **iron:router** I managed doing it by adding

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet"> <!-- to render icons -->
```

in **common** template which is set as **layoutTemplate** in:

```
Router.configure({
    loadingTemplate: 'loading', // template displayed over the current view(template) while it's being loaded
    layoutTemplate: 'common' // common template to the various views (including Polymer elements import)
});
```